# Function with pointer arguments inside another function?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm very new to C (and coding in general) so I apologize if this is a stupid question. What I have is a function that takes an integer pointer as one of it's arguments, and i'm trying to call it from inside another function.

for example:

```
int a;

void function1(int* a)
{
/* Code */
}

void function2(int* a)
{
   function1(&a);
}
```

I don't know how to call the function or if this is even the proper way to do this. Basically I need function 1 to be able to change the value of "a" in main when it is called in function 2. Thanks :)

Comment: Looks fine. You can just try it instead of asking.

Comment: You need to realise that `function1` hides the globally-scoped version of `a`, and instead will only see the pointer you pass in.  So if you want `function1` to modify the global `a` then you need to pass it `&a`, just like you are doing in `function2`.  The example seems a bit contrived though.  And it's not clear whether you are actually asking what you think you're asking.

Comment: Yeah im sorry for the unclear question Its tough when I don't know the proper names to call things haha. I edited the argument for function 2 to show what I have right now and its giving me the error "Passing argument from incompatible pointer type"

Comment: `function1(&a);` --> `function1(a);`

Comment: My thought process is that I'm trying to make function1 point to the argument in function2 which points to the original variable "a".

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you that worked :) Pointers still confuse me

Comment: @IsmailBadawi: It is wrong. And learning C by trial&error is very bad advice.

Comment: Any reason you don't simply `return` a pointer and assign it in the caller to whatever pointer you have? Provide a [mcve] and be more specific about what you want to achieve, not just what you do.

Comment: @Olaf It isn't evident in my example but function1 does a job that is required in function2, both functions have multiple arguments, it just happened that I needed function1 to change a value outside of function2, so in my case I don't think returning a pointer would have worked. However I might be misunderstanding your comment and you might be right. Again sorry for the unclear description/example.

Comment: @JamesDrouin: One of the most important (and often most complicated) jobs in programming is designing the interface between modules and functions. That is one of the differences between a programmer and a software developer. But it can safe a lot of trouble like debugging, refactoring and discussion with colleagues.

Comment: @Olaf It was edited. It was correct when I commented.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi: I see. Sorry then! It's always a problem if posters change their question. It is allowed only until there is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter 'a' of function2 is already a pointer, so you should pass 'a', not '&a', to function1 within function2. What you are doing now is passing the address of the element storing the pointer, rather than the pointer itself. When you call function2 in your main() code, however, you should pass '&a' to it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining :)